# Why won't assertions work? Ruby Unit Test Error: undefined method `add_assertion' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, object, assertion

I'm trying to use Ruby assertion functions, and I keep getting the same error:
undefined method `add_assertion' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'test/unit'
require_relative 'functions'

class TestObj < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def initialize()
  end

  def test_me(obj)
    for i in 0..2
      assert_equal('ok', obj.a_function(input1, input2))
    end
  end
end

function_session = my_object.new()
test_session = TestValuePair.new()

test_session.test_me(function_session)
```

I've already tried including the assertion library like so:

```
require "test/unit/assertions"
include Test::Unit::Assertions
```

Neither of my objects take any arguments to be initialized. I also know that the my_object object does work.
Anyone have any insight?

Comment: what is `TestValuePair` because this is the object you are calling `test_me` on.